# Integrating $ (\cos ^3 x - \sin^3 x)^{-1}$

Tags: integration

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\cos^3 x-\sin ^3 x}=\int \frac {(\cos x-\sin x) dx}{(\cos x -\sin x)^2 (1+\sin x \cos x)}=\int \frac{2(\cos x-\sin x)dx}{(1-\sin 2x)(2+\sin 2x)}$$
$$\implies I=\frac{2}{3} \int (\cos x - \sin x) {\left(\frac{1}{1-\sin 2x}+ \frac{1}{2+\sin 2x}\right)}dx$$
$$\implies I=\frac{2}{3} \int (\cos x - \sin x) {\left(\frac{1}{2-(\sin x+ \cos x)^2}+ \frac{1}{1+(\sin x+\cos x)^2}\right)}dx.$$
Let us use $\sin x+\cos x=t$. Finally,we get
$$I=\frac{2}{3}\int\left( \frac{1}{2-t^2}+\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}} \log \left|\frac{\sqrt{2}-(\sin x+\cos x)}{\sqrt{2}+(\sin x+\cos x)}\right|+\frac{2}{3}\tan^{-1}(\sin x+\cos x)+C.$$

Looking at a solution, it looks natural and perhaps unique. The question is: How else it can be done.

Comment: The standard-but-tedious use of the Weierstrass substitution, $t = \tan(x/2)$, probably applies.

Comment: Probably this is the simplest way to integrate it.

Comment: One may also substitute $x=\sin^{-1}y$, then try an [Euler sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). The result is$$-\frac23\int\left(\frac2{z^2+2z-1}+\frac{z^2+2z-1}{z^4-2z^3+2z^2+2z+1}\right)\,dz$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is the write
$$\frac 32 \frac{1}{\cos ^3(x)-\sin ^3(x)}=\frac{\cos (x)-\sin (x)}{1+(\sin (x)+\cos (x))^2}+\frac{\sec
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{ 2- \left(\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)^2}$$

The first integral is obvious and the second is simple.

Answer (score 0):

In general, with the substitution $t=\sin x+\cos x$
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{\cos^{2n+1}x-\sin^{2n+1}x}\ dx\\
=& \ \frac{2^n}{1+2n}\int \bigg( \frac{1}{2-t^2}+2\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k}\frac{\cos a_k \cos^{n-1}2a_k}{\sec 2a_k+1-t^2} \bigg)dt\\
\end{align} with $a_k=\frac{\pi k}{2n+1}$.